# Inserting content of files as a table in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, file, sql-insert

With the code below Im trying to insert the content of my files into a table I have created manually in MySQL workbench. The table has 7 columns, the files have 5 columns and 11 rows (tab oriented). What Im actually doing is: Reading the files, placing the content  in a list. Add 2 columns to that list to complete 7 columns and then inserting that list into MySQL.

**The Problem is:**
When I run this code, the MySQL table gets populated (which is good!). However it happens just for 1 file. I just get 11 rows in my table. While I (in this example) have inserted 3 files in that list. So I expect 3 x 11 rows in my MySQL table. How is this possible?

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime


#Make a connection with the workbench
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host= 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '*****',
        database= 'db_one'
    )

cursor = mydb.cursor()

select_post = "SELECT * FROM `table0`"

cursor.execute(select_post)

source = r'c:\data\JS\Desktop\Source'

names_mysql= [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
names_folder= os.listdir(source)

     def table01():
#look for corresponding names in the names_folder.
    for x in names_folder:
        if x in names_mysql:
            subdir_path = os.path.join(source, x) 
            for file in os.listdir(subdir_path):
              a = os.path.join(subdir_path, file)
  
#Get creation time of the files.            
                mode_time = os.path.getctime(a)
                rmode_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(mode_time))
                            
#Place all absolute paths in a list.        
            all_paths= [os.path.join(subdir_path, file) for file in os.listdir(subdir_path)]
            if all_paths!= []:
                newest_paths= max(all_paths, key=os.path.getctime)
                print(newest_paths)              
                            
#Read the content of files into a list.        
                for file in all_paths:
                    if file == newest_paths and os.path.getctime(newest_paths) < time.time() - 120:
                        with open(file, 'rt') as f:
                            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
                            line_data0 = list()
                            col = next(reader)
                                                                    
#Add 2 columns to that list.                         
                            for line in reader:
                                line.insert(0, x)
                                line.insert(1, rmode_time)
                                if line != []:
                                    line_data0.append(line)
                            print(line_data0)             
                            cursor = mydb.cursor()
                         
                            cursor.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE table1')
                                               
                            query1 = ("INSERT INTO table1 "
                                     "(`Post`,`DateTime`,`Sys`,`PP`,`AA`, `KJ`, `Status`)"
                                     "VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s)")
        
        
                            for p in line_data0:
                                cursor.execute(query1, p)
     mydb.commit()
     mydb.close()


table01()
```

Please note my aim is to constantly rewrite the table. So everytime I run the code I expect 3 new files in the workbench (33 rows).

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE table1` clears the table in every loop. Also, you seem to check if the file is the (one) newest file (`if file == newest_paths`), so your loop code might only be executed with one (newest) file, not sure what the intention is with that.

Comment: @Solarflare. I need to take just the newest file of each folder, thats why. Do I need to place TRUNCATE TABLE outside the loop?

Comment: Yes, truncate definitely should be called only once (maybe directly after `def table01():`)

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you very much!! I placed it right before def and this worked perfectly! By the way, iam very eager to learn so I would like to ask what you think of the code. Is it proper?